# Right Callout Accessory button not visible on annotation View for this code

Tags: objective-c, ios, button, mkmapview, mkannotation

I have this following function implemented in my app

There are no errors at compile time. Yet I cannot see the right accessory button on my map annotations in the simulator. I see the annotation, its just that there is no button on it.
Is there a trick to this that Im missing?

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id 
 <MKAnnotation>)annotation
 {
    static NSString *identifier = @"Vendor";

    //Set upt the right accessory button
    UIButton *myDetailAccessoryButton = [UIButton 
    buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    myDetailAccessoryButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 23, 23);
    myDetailAccessoryButton.contentVerticalAlignment = 
    UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    myDetailAccessoryButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = 
    UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;

    [myDetailAccessoryButton addTarget:self
                            action:nil
                  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

     if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[Vendor class]])
     {

       MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *) [self.mapView

       dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
       if (annotationView == nil)
      {
        annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]
                          initWithAnnotation:annotation
                          reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = myDetailAccessoryButton;
        annotationView.enabled = YES;
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
        annotationView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(-5, 5);

    }
    else
    {
        annotationView.annotation = annotation;
    }

    return annotationView;
     }

     return nil;
   }
```

EDIT 
This code worked but the above one doesn't.

Why is that?

```
   if ([annotation isMemberOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
    return nil;

 MKPinAnnotationView *annView=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]
                               initWithAnnotation:annotation
                               reuseIdentifier:@"currentloc"];


   UIButton *myDetailButton = [UIButton 
   buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    myDetailButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 23, 23);
    myDetailButton.contentVerticalAlignment = 
    UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    myDetailButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = 
   UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;

[myDetailButton addTarget:self
                   action:nil
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    annView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = myDetailButton;

   annView.animatesDrop=NO;
   annView.canShowCallout = YES;
   annView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(-5, 5);
   return annView;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you're adding annotations of type `Vendor`?

Because the first code block only sets the `rightCalloutAccessoryView` for annotations of type `Vendor`.  For any other type, it returns `nil` resulting in a generic callout (no buttons).

The second code block sets the `rightCalloutAccessoryView` for any annotation type except `MKUserLocation`.

By the way, you've set the button action to `nil` which means nothing will happen when it's tapped.